# Auto-aliasing issues when selecting by relationship count with SQLAlchemy + Postgres

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

Given the following code:

```python
from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey, Integer, alias, create_engine, func, select
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base, relationship, sessionmaker

Base = declarative_base()
engine = create_engine(
    "postgresql+psycopg2://***:***@127.0.0.1:5432/***", future=True
)

Session = sessionmaker(engine)


class Foo(Base):
    __tablename__ = "foo"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    bars = relationship("Bar", uselist=True, secondary="foo_bar")
    baz_id = Column(ForeignKey("baz.id"))
    baz = relationship("Baz", back_populates="foos", lazy="joined")


class Bar(Base):
    __tablename__ = "bar"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)


class Baz(Base):
    __tablename__ = "baz"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    foos = relationship(Foo, uselist=True)


class FooBar(Base):
    __tablename__ = "foo_bar"
    foo_id = Column(ForeignKey(Foo.id), primary_key=True)
    bar_id = Column(ForeignKey(Bar.id), primary_key=True)


Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

stmt = (
    select(Foo)
    .join(FooBar, FooBar.foo_id == Foo.id)
    .group_by(Foo.id)
    .having(func.count(FooBar.foo_id) == 2)
)

Session().execute(stmt)
```

I want to select all `Foo`s with exactly two `Bar`s.

But I'm running into the following error:

```bash
column "baz_1.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

The generated SQL is:

```sql
SELECT foo.id, foo.baz_id, baz_1.id AS id_1 
FROM foo JOIN foo_bar ON foo_bar.foo_id = foo.id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN baz AS baz_1 ON baz_1.id = foo.baz_id GROUP BY foo.id 
HAVING count(foo_bar.foo_id) = :count_1
```

Now I get what Postgres wants me to do, but I'm not sure how to achieve this, since I can't add `baz_1.id` to the `GROUP PY` clause because it's something that SQLAlchemy generates on the fly and I don't have any control over it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Baz` is being included in the query because of the `lazy='joined'` option on the relationship in `Foo`.  We can override that option in the query, so that the join is not executed and the query works as desired.

```py
stmt = (
    select(Foo)
    .options(orm.lazyload(Foo.baz))  # <- don't automatically join Baz.
    .join(FooBar, FooBar.foo_id == Foo.id)
    .group_by(Foo.id)
    .having(func.count(FooBar.foo_id) == 2)
)
```

Generated SQL:

```sql
SELECT foo.id, foo.baz_id 
FROM foo 
JOIN foo_bar ON foo_bar.foo_id = foo.id 
GROUP BY foo.id 
HAVING count(foo_bar.foo_id) = %(count_1)s
```

Comment: I asked the same question in the SQLAlchemy discussions over on Github and got detailed explanation as to what's happening. For anyone interested, here's the link:  https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/discussions/7775#discussioncomment-2260729.